# nginx location “~*” and "~" modifier not working in macOS

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration：

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name localhost; 
  root /nginx-root/html/;

  location ~ \.(png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    return 200 "OK1";
  }

  location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    return 200 "OK2";
  }
}
```

then I enter "curl http://localhost/nginx.PNG", and expected return "OK2", but actually is "OK1", Is there something wrong with my computer configuration?

Comment: You aren't using a case sensitive filesystem.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this

Comment: Well, it's not about filesystem, but OS. See https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/87#comment:4 for workaround and possible problems.